# My Applications are not showing after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, 20.04

I did an upgrade today to the latest version of ubuntu. Everything looked good and fine only for me to discover that I cannot find my applications after clicking the '*Show Applications*' icon. The same applies when I search for an application in the search bar, I do not see it. It shows me an endless search.

These are the screenshot images of the problem:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

In the meantime, I access my applications from the menu at the top bar and also use the terminal to run applications with CLI.

Comment: I also have this issue. Additionally, when I click "Frequent" at the bottom of the application list (to show frequently used applications), the desktop environment briefly crashes. Does this also happen for you?

Comment: @SpencerDub Yes, I also have this same issue. It crashes briefly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In my case, this was being caused by an extension. In my particular case once I deactivated the **Appfolders management** extension which I had included in 18.04 LTS and restarted the computer everything worked perfectly.

Here's how to do that if you can't access your applications via the Launcher:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open a Terminal window.
2. In the Terminal, type `gnome-tweaks` and hit Enter. This will launch the GNOME Tweaks application.
3. In GNOME Tweaks, click Extensions in the left-hand pane.
4. Deactivate individual extensions by clicking the switch next to them. Alternatively, you can use the switch at the top of the window to deactivate all extensions at once.
5. When you have deactivated the extensions, you need to restart your shell. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open a '*Run a Command*' dialog.
6. In the 'Run a Command' dialog, type `r` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will restart the shell.
7. Open your launcher to see if the problem is fixed. Use these steps and the process of elimination to determine if an extension is causing the bugged behavior.

Comment: I just did as you said and it worked instantly. 
You don't actually have to restart the computer, you can just use `ALT` + `F2` and input `r`.
Thanks a bunch, Andre, you are a real MVP.

Comment: I just noticed a little bug there. It doesn't respond perfectly well especially when you open folders already grouped. Though, I believe the next update would fix it.
I can still run around with it for now.

Comment: This was my experience as well. I completely reinstalled 20.04, including wiping the drive, and it worked swimmingly until I reactivated Appfolders Management. Deactivating it again fixed the problem.

Andre, I'm going to edit your answer with some keyboard shortcuts so people who are used to the GUI can use this answer. :)

Comment: Amazing - how did you think to try this?

Comment: Did not work for me - I don't have an option for disabling extensions. Also I cannot search for "r" or anything else, as the search window simply says "no results found...".
I don't see anything in my launcher. Do you any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have an "Extensions" option in Tweaks.

Comment: Great find. I was having the same issue and now it is solved by removing the extention. Thank you for the answer. Only when we remove appfolder management extension, how can we make folders inside the shell is unknown to me.

Comment: OMG. I love you! This is awesome. I was just about to re-install Gnome (but learned from other posts that it doesn't help). This fixed my issue! Thank you so much!

Comment: For 22.04, you'd need to install first the extension manager with `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager`. Launch it with "extension-manager". From there, disable user extension. For me, I found some stale extension, once disabled, the apps are now showing.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue even though my extensions were disabled. It turned out to be caused by having the new theme - Yaru (previously called Communitheme) - installed on 18.04 before upgrade. After switching from  Communitheme to Yaru in Gnome tweak tool and from "Ubuntu Communitheme" to "Ubuntu" during login under gear icon, the issue went away.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I had something similar after upgrading 18.04 -> 20.04. When pressing the Meta / Win key, I only got an overview of open windows, but neither the sidebar for applications, nor the search bar for applications and files. I logged out and switched from GNOME classic to GNOME and everything worked as before...

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem, activities 3x3 cluster icon did nothing anymore after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. I toggled back all themes to the default and something else than Yaru and then it magically started working again...

Answer (score 2):

I disabled *all* GNOME extensions as suggested by [pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky) and after a restart of GNOME-shell the applications were shown again in the dash!
Afterwards I reactived one GNOME extension after the other and finally, when I came to the appfolder-management extension, the applications were gone again. So I deactivated the appfolder-management extension again and everything were fine again.

So I can confirm, that there's a problem with the appfolder-management extension but to be safe you have to disable **ALL** extensions first and then reactivate them **EXCEPT** the appfolder-managment extension. Furthermore, after GNOME shell 3.33 there's no need for that extension, because after 3.33, GNOME Shell handles this feature natively.

Comment: In GNOME Shell 3.36.7 how can one use that extension feature natively? Can you please share? Thank you! :)