# Activities button in Ubuntu 20.04 not working

Tags: launcher, 20.04

Recently upgraded to 20.04. When I click on the Activities button, it is nothing more than a search bar.

Home icon: "Sorry there is nothing that matches your search." I can type anything in there and NOTHING shows up.
Application icon: Same as above.
Document icon: Same as above.

I'm just trying to find the installed application icons... I need my launcher!

Comment: I have a similar problem and just noticed that my keyboard layout was switched. I have a German keyboard and the problem seems to occur when I switch from the German layout to the English layout. Once I switch back the button works normally. Is this the same for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was caused by the "Appfolders management extension" GNOME extension.

If you're using that extension, [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231097/947989) might help you disable the extension and get your applications list working again.