# Dash empty after upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, gnome-shell, 20.04

I've upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` (because the new 20.04-version didn't show up with the normal update-manager). Everything's went fine, output from `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04
LTS Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
```

except that my dash is empty since that upgrade:
[image: image of empty dash]

My dock is ok, it still shows the applications (I'm using dash-to-dock extension). 
Can anyone help me getting back my entries in the dash, please?

I deactivated appfolder-management extension as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231097); the extension was not active at all, did a reboot -> no success. Then I changed theme from Radiance to Yaru and used Ubuntu for login (as always) -> no success.

Additionally, when I click "Frequent" at the bottom of the application list (to show frequently used applications), the desktop environment briefly crashes.