# Should I report Show Applications not scrolling as a bug?

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, bug-reporting

Please bear with me, as I have never filed a bug report before. I have browsed [ReportingBugs - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), but I found the amount of information slightly overwhelming.

The issue that I have been encountering was mentioned here on Ask Ubuntu ([Show Applications not scrolling after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 (via 19.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236559/show-applications-not-scrolling-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-from-18-04-via-19)), in which I am not able to scroll to the second page of Show Applications. I can not view all of my installed programs since they take up two pages, and I can only view the first.

[image: Activities overview]

My issue differs slightly from they post linked above, since I performed a fresh install of Ubuntu. Something else that was not mentioned in the other post was that as soon as I switch from Frequent to All Applications, the dots on the right (which allow me to switch through the list of applications) as well as the Frequent and All buttons, start to jitter vertically. My issue is identical to the linked post in every other way. At the time of writing this, the only solution provided to that question was to disconnect a secondary monitor, but I am running Ubuntu on a netbook with only the primary display. I am able to search for applications, but the **Searching...** text jitters as well. Interestingly, as soon as I take a screenshot, the **Searching...** text stops jittering. (Note: if I search under the Frequent tab, nothing jitters. There is only jittering under the All tab.)

[image: search]

I have converted a screen capture I took into these GIFs for the purpose of this post, and I will attempt to include the whole video in my actual bug report. The GIFs illustrate the jittering, the button not advancing through my apps, and the jittering of the **Searching...** text.

[image: Jittering]
[image: Can't see second page]
[image: Searching... text jitters]

---

**Update:** [Reported as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1879600)

---

Comment: I'm not a GNOME user, so I don't understand your issue sorry, and that does reduce my information. Asking for advice on a support site before filing a bug is a good thing in my opinion (allows you to define your bug clearer) and I hope you get meaningful help. I suspect the package is `gnome-shell`, thus bug report would be via `ubuntu-bug gnome-shell` on your actual system (so information gained by `ubuntu-bug` gets it from your actual box). You need to include description, AND what you expect to happen, AND what actually happened (breaking into parts/sections can help). Include link to here

Comment: ps:  devs cannot know about the issue until it's reported, if no-one reports expect it to remain that way forever (unless a dev notices it). I'd wait for others to respond here, esp. GNOME users who understand your issue better than I do too.  I'm giving my 2c  ps:  my comments relate to bug report; not this site; ie. my 2c on what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just changed my post to include some other details about the bug, but I will include your suggestions.

Comment: I have witnessed this in Ubuntu running at a resolution of 1024x768. Once I increased the resolution, the issue went away. I agree this seems like a bug worth reporting. Once you do, please link the Bug report (or Bug number here), and I will mark myself as impacted, so they know that multiple people have encountered this issue.

Comment: @PJSingh I had a similar idea (you will see in my bug report once I have posted it), since the computer's max resolution it 1024x600.

Comment: @PJSingh I have linked the bug report at the end of the post. I have edited it to include that another user had encountered this problem at low resolution.

Comment: What I mean to say is that in the reproduction section of my bug report I have mentioned that someone else noticed this at low resolution as well, and I am suggesting the devs should lower their display resolution to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is something worth reporting. Thankfully, there's a handy built-in tool in Ubuntu that can help collect most of the necessary information.

`ubuntu-bug gnome-shell` in a terminal should collect a bit of information about the version of the `gnome-shell` package installed, dependencies, some hardware info, and Ubuntu version, etc. Then it should open up a web browser window where you can sign in to Launchpad (or create an account) and provide details about the bug. Feel free to also link to your post here if you feel some of the details/info you've provided here are critical or useful.
[The Ubuntu Bug Window You Should See When Running ubuntu-bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm7Ty.png)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is looking for a temporary fix to this issue:

Yes, it happens when your dock is displayed on the left side of the screen. It's a bug as far as I know.

There are three workarounds:

1. If you use a dual-screen setup, try detaching and reattaching the secondary screen.
2. Go to Settings → *Appearance* → *Position on Screen* → *Right* or *Bottom*. Changing dock position solves the issue somehow.
3. Running this in your terminal will help you solve it if you like the dock to be on the left side only:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
   ```